# Open question in abstract model theory

Tags: model-theory

The existence of  an extension of
first order logic satisfying both the Compactness Theorem and the Interpolation
Theorem is an open or solved question?

Comment: What properties does an "extension of first order logic" need to satisfy (e.g. relativization, isomorphism-invariance, etc.)? With no restrictions, I think uninteresting examples of such logics can be constructed pretty easily.

Comment: Also, can you give any background to this problem? I've heard about it before, and I understand it has an interesting history, but that's the extent of my knowledge about it; and I'd be curious to hear anything you might say about it.